# error when saving multiple (onetoonefield) forms in django views.py. pls, Need correct working view or suggestion

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

username = None
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True) 
mobileno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = UserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email


class VendorDetails(models.Model):

vendoruser = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
aadhar_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pan_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
store_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
mail_id = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
contact_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
gst_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
acct_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
ifsc_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
fb_account = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
insta_account = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True) 
website = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
door_no = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
street_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
pincode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)



def __str__(self):
    return self.mail_id
```

forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
"""
A Custom form for creating new users.
"""

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ['email','first_name','last_name','mobileno']


 """ For Vendor users forms"""

class VendorAdminDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = VendorDetails
    fields = ['aadhar_number', 'pan_number']


class VendorStoreDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = VendorDetails
    fields = ['store_name', 'brand_name', 'mail_id', 'contact_no', 'gst_number']


class VendorBankDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = VendorDetails
    fields = ['acct_number', 'ifsc_code']


class VendorSocialMediaDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

fb_account = forms.CharField(required=False)
insta_account = forms.CharField(required=False) 
website = forms.CharField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = VendorDetails
    fields = ['fb_account', 'insta_account', 'website']


class VendorContactDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

door_no = forms.CharField(required=False)
street_name = forms.CharField(required=False) 
pincode = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = VendorDetails
    fields = ['door_no', 'street_name', 'city', 'pincode']
```

views.py

```
 #Vendor Signup
 def VendorSignup(request):
     form = UserCreationForm()
     vendordetail = VendorAdminDetailsForm()
     vendorstore = VendorStoreDetailsForm()
     vendorbankdetail = VendorBankDetailsForm()
     vendorsocialmedia = VendorSocialMediaDetailsForm()
     vendorcontact = VendorContactDetailsForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    vendordetail = VendorAdminDetailsForm(request.POST)
    vendorstore = VendorStoreDetailsForm(request.POST)
    vendorbankdetail = VendorBankDetailsForm(request.POST)
    vendorsocialmedia = VendorSocialMediaDetailsForm(request.POST)
    vendorcontact = VendorContactDetailsForm(request.POST)
    
    if form.is_valid() and vendordetail.is_valid() and vendorstore.is_valid() and vendorbankdetail.is_valid() and vendorsocialmedia.is_valid() and vendorcontact.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print("form")
        vendordetail.save()
        vendorstore.save()
        vendorbankdetail.save()
        vendorsocialmedia.save()
        vendorcontact.save()
        return redirect('login')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()
    vendordetail = VendorAdminDetailsForm()
    vendorstore = VendorStoreDetailsForm()
    vendorbankdetail = VendorBankDetailsForm()
    vendorsocialmedia = VendorSocialMediaDetailsForm()
    vendorcontact = VendorContactDetailsForm()
```

I have created multiple forms for signup with extending abstractuser model. also I have put all these forms in template separately. Is it the correct way to handle multiple forms. Facing issue in the line (vendordetail.save()) Not null field (onetoonefield related issue). But I don't know how to write views for this all forms. Please help me to get this solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you inserting the correct `vendoruser`? That needs to be filled in prior to calling save().

You need to do something like:

```
vendordetail.instance.vendoruser = request.user
```

If indeed `vendoruser` is the user that's currently logged in, else you need to get it from somewhere else. After insertion you can call:

```
vendordetail.save()
```

Edit: I missed that you are creating your user on the same page in another form. In that case you can first save your user form:

```
new_user = form.save()
```

The save() method of a model form will return the new object, therefore you can use it afterwards for your other forms:

```
vendordetail.instance.vendoruser = new_user
```

Comment: i inserted the above line before vendordetail.save(). but got error - (ValueError at /vendor/signup/
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x00000269C17B2730>>": "VendorDetails.vendoruser" must be a "CustomUser" instance.).

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Yes you can do it with every form (if all models have a required field for user)

Comment: can i save user instance before every form.save(). also user is not logged in. so getting the user instance is not possible, I think. But I want save this model for a user before login.

Comment: Yes you can do it for every form, but it needs a logged-in user. Otherwise you will have an anonymous user as request.user, and that won't work. Surely you don't want anonymous users to save database objects?

Comment: yes. I need to save the entire vendordetails model for the current requested user but this can be done in while the user Signup. Is it possible? then, how can I do it?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: new_user = form.save()
    print("form")
vendordetail.instance.vendoruser = new_user
       vendordetail.save()
    vendorstore.instance.vendoruser = new_user
       vendorstore.save()
     vendorbankdetail.instance.vendoruser = new_user
      vendorbankdetail.save()
   vendorsocialmedia.instance.vendoruser = new_user
    vendorsocialmedia.save()
      vendorcontact.instance.vendoruser = new_user
     vendorcontact.save()
            return redirect('login')   . error appeared in line vendorstore.save() -UNIQUE constraint failed: customer_vendordetails.vendoruser_id

Comment: Argh! You're using the same model for all your forms!! On the same page!! Each with different fields! Why don't you just create one `ModelForm` for `VendorDetails`? Then insert your `new_user` once, and save it once? There is no need for all these different forms. If you insist, you can get the values of what's submitted in the other little forms and set them individually on the vendordetail.instance but seriously, just use one form for one model.

Comment: sorry for more disturbing you. I am a newbie, I don't know this basic thing. if i did, there are two forms one form for user basicdetail another is vendordetail form. but if it is, I will have two submit buttons.how can i do this same time. This is my last comment in this chat. Thanks for answering my silly questions.

Comment: @sam It's ok buddy. No worries. You just do the ModelForm for the whole form instead of the part-forms you've done now.                `class VendorDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = VendorDetails
    fields = ['put every single field here that you need']` and then forget about all the other part-forms. You just need one form + your usercreation form (although I still think you should log users in first)

Comment: @Limecate yes, I modified this. Now it is working. I can save user instances with storedetails. Thankyou very much for your great help.